# Why use abstract type keyword in Julia?

Tags: inheritance, julia, abstract

What is the purpose of the 'abstract types' in Julia? Is there a use aside from using the type for the inheritance hierarchy?

```
abstract Animal

type Dog <: Animal
  sound
  color
end

type Bird <: Animal
  sound
  color
end
```

What is the purpose of this if it does not give the ability to inherit attributes and methods?

Answer (score 11):

Probably worth [reading through the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-abstract-types-1) for this, as there are many uses for them.

Quoting from the manual one example:

> Abstract types allow the construction of a hierarchy of types, providing a context into which concrete types can fit. This allows you, for example, to easily program to any type that is an integer, without restricting an algorithm to a specific type of integer.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> if it does not give the ability to inherit attributes and methods?

But I disagree with that notion.

If you're thinking of `abstract type` as being like abstract classes in Java, that's probably tenuous at best. Start by thinking of them as interfaces. Let's say we wanted to have an *interface* `Named` for anything which has a reasonable concept of a name.

```
abstract type Named end
nameof(::Named) = ""
```

If you really wanted to, you could throw an exception in `nameof` if there's no reasonable default value.

Now, anybody can come along and *subscribe* to that interface.

```
struct Person <: Named
  name :: String
end
nameof(p::Person) = p.name
```

Now, let's say we want to say something about an entity, which may or may not have a name. We can use the name if it exists and fall back if not

```
message(entity, msg::String) = print(nameof(entity), " says ", msg)
message(entity::Named, msg::String) = print(nameof(entity), " says ", msg)
```

So you should think of `abstract type` as being like a Java interface but extensible, so we can "implement" the interface for existing types, such as built-in types and types we don't control. A type subscribes to the interface, which presumably defines a minimal set of functions, and then several other functions act on that interface, automatically extending to work on any type that's opted into the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can enforce an association to prevent accidentally mixing types. Make sure that birds don't get dog food, and that neither animal receives fertilizer intended for plants, say.

Another example: companies that invoice in dollars vs companies that invoice in euros. If done properly, you won't be accidentally adding dollars and euros.

```
abstract type Currency end

struct dollar <: Currency
    amazon
    apple
end

struct euro <: Currency
    adidas
    mercedes
end
```